# Angular CLI Include style sheet scss file in library build

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

I am following these examples to create reusable libraries.

https://medium.com/@tomsu/how-to-build-a-library-for-angular-apps-4f9b38b0ed11

https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e

When I run `ng build library-name` , I don't get *.scss file in the dist/library-name folder. How do I include style sheets in my build?

**Some useful posts on this**

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11071

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11317

https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr/issues/839#issuecomment-386791207

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gulp for build and publish components to a npm repository.
Followings are the steps:

1. Define build paths in tsconfig.json

[image]

2. Library components need to packaging under lib directory.
3. Write a gulp task to build components. (e.g. gulp command : gulp build)
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-build
4. Run 'gulp build'
5. From this method we can publish .scss files bundle with the relevant library component.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The styles are added to the library bundles as JavaScript code. Unless you disable all view encapsulation for all of your components, then WebPack will create a static css file.

Comment: Thanks. so I did following for one of the component and still dont see scss file . Do you see anything wrong here: 

import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.None

Comment: @ProgSky try building for production.

Comment: hmm. I tried ng build library-name --prod and still nothing. I think I will have to research more on this. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: It use to work that way. I know they've changed a lot of how webpack works in Angular 6.

Comment: Looks like they broke support for this in Angular 6. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10869

Answer (score 1):

You may write build script in package.json that will copy the styles files to a folder in the dist/lib folder (probably with a copy package like 'cpx')